Add vector layer from PostGIS table to existing data store using Python geoserver-restconfig
I am trying add a vector layer from PostGIS table to an existing datastore. Does geoserver-restconfig allow this?
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog

cat = Catalog(service_url=serv_url, username='admin', password='password')
epsg_code = 'EPSG:3857'

datastore = cat.get_store(store_name, workspace='workspace1')
feature_type = cat.publish_featuretype(layer_name, datastore, epsg_code) 

The last line produces this error:
ERROR  [geoserver.rest] - No such feature type: workspace1,store1,test_layer1
org.geoserver.rest.ResourceNotFoundException 404 NOT_FOUND: No such feature type: workspace1,store1,test_layer1

Is it possible to add a vector layer from PostGIS table to an existing datastore with geoserver-restconfig?

For loading geojson to PostGIS you can use:
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=postgres port=5432 dbname="knetwork" user=postgres password=k_network" "file_name.geojson" -nln table-name -dim 2 -overwrite

I would suggest you to use below code for publish layer
BASE_URL - http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/rest


def publish_layer(self, workspace: str, store_name: str, layer_name: str):
        # url = f"/workspaces/{workspace}/coveragestores/{store_name}/coverages?configure=all&recalculate=nativebbox,latlonbbox"
        url = f"{self.base_url}/workspaces/{workspace}/datastores/{store_name}/featuretypes"
        headers = {"content-type": "text/xml"}
        data = f"<featureType><name>{layer_name}</name></featureType>"

        session = requests.Session()
        session.trust_env = False
        r = session.post(
            url, auth=(self.username, self.password), data=data, headers=headers
        )

        print(f"Layer {layer_name} published!", r.status_code, r.reason)
        if r.status_code not in [200, 201]:
            return "{}: Data store can not be created! {}".format(
                r.status_code, r.content
            )



